# Access VBA 2007 passing a form as a parameter

Tags: ms-access, vba

We are trying to reduce duplicate code in our access database. We have severalforms what we use the following sort of code on.

```
strSQL = "Some SQL"
Me!cboClientName.RowSource = strSQL
Me!cboClientName.BoundColumn = 2
Me!cboClientName.ColumnCount = 2
Me!cboClientName.ColumnWidths = "0cm ; 2 cm"
```

What I wanted to do is create a sub routine and pass the form into it and then replace the Me with the object.

So I now have something like this:

```
Public Sub subName(myForm as Form)
    strSQL = "SELECT [tblClients].[ID], [tblClients].[ClientName] FROM [tblClients] ORDER BY [ClientName]"
    myForm !cboClientName.RowSource = strSQL
    myForm !cboClientName.BoundColumn = 2
    myForm !cboClientName.ColumnCount = 2
    myForm !cboClientName.ColumnWidths = "0cm ; 2 cm"
```

cboClientName is on every form that I am calling it on. I then am calling the sub routine using.

```
subName(Me)
```

I am however getting the error:

```
Type mis match ... 13
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way todo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be

```
 subName Me
```

No brackets.

Further information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251710.aspx

Comment: I am not sure what you wish to do so please forgive me if this is obvious to you, but do you know that you can set bound column, count and widths and these properties will be saved with the form, so you only need to update the SQL as required?